# Find length of an arc.

Tags: calculus

Find the length of the arc formed by 
$x^2=12y^3$ 
from point $A$ to point $B$, where 
$A=(0,0)$ and $B=(144,12)$

so this is what I have so far:
$f(x)=(\frac{x^2}{12})^{1/3}$,
$f'(x) = \frac{(\frac23)^{1/3} x}{3 (x^2)^{2/3}}$
And the limits are $0$ - $144$

The formula I need to use is $L=\int_a^b \sqrt{1+[f'(x)]^2}dx$

Why am I getting the wrong answer?
Can you explain the steps.

Comment: You will find it a bit challenging to integrate $ \ \sqrt{1 \ + \ (\frac{2}{3^4})^{2/3}\frac{1}{x^{2/3}} } $ , but at least it _has_ a closed-form expression.  Inverting the integral to work in terms of $ \ y \ $ , as **David H** suggests, is really the easier way to go...  You would use  $ \ L \ = \ \int_0^{12} \sqrt{1+[\frac{dx}{dy}]^2} \ \ dy \ $ .

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This problem is much easier tackled viewing $x$ as a function of $y$ instead of the other way around. We have

$$x=f(y)=\sqrt{12}y^{3/2},\\
f'(y)=3\sqrt{3y},\\
[f'(y)]^2=27y.$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I should have thought of that when I saw the mess of an answer I was getting!